# Query that display all dates in a range

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a query that displays dates and counts. I want to display all dates within a range including dates with zero counts. I am looking for a way to do this WITHOUT using temp tables.

The output might look like:

```
Time               Count
1/1/2017 01:00 AM  23
1/1/2017 02:00 AM  0
1/1/2017 03:00 AM  0
1/1/2017 04:00 AM  12
```

Comment: So what is your question? Or are you looking for someone writing the query from scratch? Show us some effort, e, g what you have tried so far and with what exactly you struggle.

Comment: What do you mean by count?

Comment: So do you want a total per hour, even if there is nothing for that hour? Maybe you want something like [`partition outer join`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312). Otherwise please post a [simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with an solutions that adds zero count rows.  An example of the result set is below.  You will see there are some duplicate DayOfWeekByHour values.   I will need to figure out how to sum those up, but this is basically what I was looking for.   See Example code link

DayOfWeekByHour, Count

100, 0

101, 0

102, 0

100, 23

201, 100

[example of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcO68.png)

```
SELECT 
    TO_NUMBER(MOD(V,7)+1 || LPAD(MOD(V,24),2,'0')) as DayOfWeekByHour, 0
FROM (
      SELECT 1 V FROM DUAL
     ) T
    MODEL DIMENSION BY (ROWNUM R)
        MEASURES (V)
        RULES ITERATE (168) (
        V[ITERATION_NUMBER] = CV(R) + 1
          )

UNION

SELECT    
    TO_NUMBER(
        TO_CHAR(
            TO_DATE(
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(DAY FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) ,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'D'),'99') * 100 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(DAY FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || ' ' || 
                    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || ':' ||
                    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) 
                    ,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
                    )
                ,'HH24'
                )
             , '99') AS DayOfWeekByHour,
     COUNT(*)
FROM 
    VIEWER.VIEWING_EVENT ve
WHERE 
    ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP >= TO_TIMESTAMP('02-12-2016 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND 
    ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP <= TO_TIMESTAMP('02-12-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY
   TO_NUMBER(
        TO_CHAR(
            TO_DATE(
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(DAY FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) ,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'D'),'99') * 100 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(DAY FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || '/' || 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || ' ' || 
                    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) || ':' ||
                    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ve.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) 
                    ,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
                    )
                ,'HH24'
                )
             , '99')
ORDER BY 
    DayOfWeekByHour
;
```

Comment: If CREATED_TIMESTAMP is stored as a date/timestamp then `trunc(created_timestamp, 'hh')` will do a lot of work for you.